# Unable to use Find with CHtmlView and URLs that have anchors

Tags: url, visual-c++, mfc, find, webbrowser-control

I am stumped on this one!

I have my own `CHtmlView` derived class and I recently added support for **Find**. I did it like this:

```
void CChristianLifeMinistryEditorDlg::OnEditFind()
{
    m_pHtmlPreview->ExecWB(OLECMDID_FIND, OLECMDEXECOPT_PROMPTUSER, nullptr, nullptr);
}
```

Under the hood the code then does the following:

```
HRESULT CChristianLifeMinistryHtmlView::ExecWB(OLECMDID cmdID, OLECMDEXECOPT cmdexecopt, VARIANT *pvaIn, VARIANT *pvaOut)
{
    ASSERT(m_pBrowserApp != nullptr);

    const auto hr = m_pBrowserApp->ExecWB(cmdID, cmdexecopt, pvaIn, pvaOut);
    return hr;
}
```

---

It works OK. But only if I render my pages this way in the browser control:

```
if (m_pHtmlPreview != nullptr)
{
    CString strURL = strPreviewXML;
    if (iBookmarkId != -1)
        strURL.Format(_T("%s#week%d"), (LPCTSTR)strPreviewXML, iBookmarkId);

    m_pHtmlPreview->Navigate2(strPreviewXML, 0, nullptr);
    //m_pHtmlPreview->Navigate2(strURL, 0, nullptr);
}
```

In short, if I navigate to the XML file itself then the finding works. But if I try to navigate to the same XMl file, but with my anchor, whilst it displays in the right place in the browser control, the Find feature then will not function:

[image]

The moment I change it back to navigating to:

```
m_pHtmlPreview->Navigate2(strPreviewXML, 0, nullptr);
```

Then the Find tool is guarenteed to work. But then this means I can no longer jump to the right part of the transformed HTML output. I tried doing:

```
m_pHtmlPreview->Navigate2(strPreviewXML, 0, nullptr);
m_pHtmlPreview->Navigate2(strURL, 0, nullptr);
```

I thought that if I navigated first to the page and then to the page with the anchor, that Find would work. But no joy. Can anything be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the mechanics of the **Find** feature does not like it when you try to navigate to the XML file which has a bookmark in the URL.

I already had code to transform the XML to a HTMl so I added that in as a secondary step:

```cpp
if (m_pHtmlPreview != nullptr)
{
    CString strURL = strPreviewXML;
    //if (iBookmarkId != -1)
    //  strURL.Format(_T("%s#week%d"), (LPCTSTR)strPreviewXML, iBookmarkId);

    //m_pHtmlPreview->Navigate2(strPreviewXML, 0, nullptr);
    CString strFileXSLPath = theApp.GetWorkingPath() + strFileXSL;
    if (theApp.MSAToolsInterface().TransformXMLToHTML(strFileXSLPath, strPreviewXML, m_strPreviewHTML))
    {
        strURL = m_strPreviewHTML;
        if(iBookmarkId != -1)
            strURL.Format(_T("%s#week%d"), (LPCTSTR)m_strPreviewHTML, iBookmarkId);

    }
    m_pHtmlPreview->Navigate2(strURL, 0, nullptr);
}
```

I find that:

1. The anchors still function correctly and jump where I want them to.
2. The Find continues to work correctly whereas it would stop function before.